# Ejecucion de consultas en sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de saber las consultas/Querys que se están ejecutando en una BD?

Esto con el fin de poder auditar la base de datos y saber que consultas están realizando interferencia o generando lentitud en la misma

Comment: Si se puede saber.

Comment: En slq server presiona "Ctrl + Alt + A" , esto abrirá el monitor de actividades, encontrarás info en tiempo real, además podrás obtener las consultas costosas que generan lentitud.

Answer (score 2):

Pues yo conozco de una, que es usando el

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests 
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es lo que devuelve, son las consultas que al momento de ejecucion del query estan  ejecutandose en tu bd, ya con esto puedes identificar que es lo que te esta generando el conflicto o lentitud en tu base de datos

al final de la consulta  te muestra cual es la sentencia ejecutada, para que puedas auditarla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

o ya si lo que quieres es determinar quien es la persona que le ejecuto, debes capturar tambien el hostname del equipo que realiza la consulta

Comment: Y es posible saber la hora en la que se ejecuto el query?

Comment: El campo start_time es la fecha y hora en la que se realizo la consulta, con ese lo puedes validar